# Python if any() does not work

Tags: python, if-statement, numpy, ipython

I want to check if any string elements in a list `phrases` contains certain keywords in a set `phd_words`. I want to use `any` but it doesn't work.

```
In[19]:
    import pandas as pd
    import psycopg2 as pg

    def test():
    phd_words = set(['doctor', 'phd'])
    phrases = ['master of science','mechanical engineering']
    for word in phrases:
        if any(keyword in word for keyword in phd_words):
            return 'bingo!'

test()

Out[20]: 
  bingo!
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: What is `phrases`?

Comment: @devnull: my bad. phrases supposed to be description. I changed the term to make it easier to understand, but forgot to do it throughout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That may happen if you use IPython's `%pylab` magic:

```
In [1]: %pylab
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib

In [2]: if any('b' in w for w in ['a', 'c']):
   ...:     print('What?')
   ...:
What?
```

Here's why:

```
In [3]: any('b' in w for w in ['a', 'c'])
Out[3]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f6756d1a948>

In [4]: any
Out[4]: <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.any>
```

`any` and `all` get shadowed with `numpy` functions, and those behave differently than the builtins. This is the reason I stopped using `%pylab` and started using `%pylab --no-import-all` so that it doesn't clobber the namespace like that.

To reach the builtin function when it is already shadowed, you can try `__builtin__.any`. The name `__builtin__` seems to be available in IPython on both Python 2 and Python 3, which is probably on itself enabled by IPython. In a script, you would first have to [`import __builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) on Python 2 and [`import builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) on Python 3.

Comment: What would possess numpy to shadow `any`?

Comment: `*` imports are evil.

Comment: @2rs2ts That's what the `%pylab` magic does: it imports stuff into the interactive namespace and enables interactive plotting. This is handy for exploratory data analysis in an IPython session. And I have to admit that the user is at least warned -- see the message above.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yeah, I realize this. I just find it a little... risky, even if anyone aware of this could `import as`.

Comment: @2rs2ts: NumPy isn't shadowing `any`. It's `import *` that shadows `any`. The whole point of namespaces is so you don't have to worry so much about using a name someone else already picked. You can see that the standard library doesn't bother to avoid built-in names; for example, `math.pow` and `codecs.open` both hide built-ins if `import *`ed.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: very interesting. I don't use `matplotlib` but I use `numpy`. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: @AdamNYC Just don't use `*` imports. And don't do `from numpy import any` if you need the builtin `any`.

Comment: I don't import `*` though. I figured just `import psychopg2` causes the issue. (See my update)

Comment: @AdamNYC If you just type `any` and hit Enter, what's the output?

Comment: I think my IPython Notebook on my server was loaded with `numpy`. When I type `any`, I got `<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.any>
`. But in local machine, with the same `import` statements, I got `<function any>`. Is there a way to rewrite the statement but using any/all function of numpy? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AdamNYC Updated the answer. `__builtin__.any` should give you the shadowed builtin `any`.

Comment: It works. Thanks a million for saving me hours, @LevLevitsky.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: unfortunately, __builtin__.any doesn't work if I need to nest it in a loop: `for word in phrases:`     
            `if __builtin__.any(keyword in word for keyword in phd_words):` returns `TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
`. Do you have more magic to help?

Comment: @AdamNYC You must have done something strange, like `phrases = __builtin__.any`. Print `phrases` to check what it is right now. Other candidates are `word` and `phd_words`.

Comment: @AdamNYC Otherwise, if there's a way I could reproduce it, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: thank you! It was caused by my bug when calling `.strip` instead of `.strip()`.